# CrossValidation in Accord.NET

Tags: c#, accord.net

Suppose we initiate cross validation with 10 folds to train Support Vector Machine, as per theory, every single fold will use a different model and based on the least cross validation error we'll select that Model, now according to Accord.NET framework this is what we use to implement cross validation:

```
var crossvalidation = new CrossValidation(size: data.Length, folds: 3);


crossvalidation.Fitting = delegate(int k, int[] indicesTrain, int[] indicesValidation)
{

// Lets now grab the training data:
var trainingInputs = data.Submatrix(indicesTrain);
var trainingOutputs = xor.Submatrix(indicesTrain);

// And now the validation data:
var validationInputs = data.Submatrix(indicesValidation);
var validationOutputs = xor.Submatrix(indicesValidation);


// Create a Kernel Support Vector Machine to operate on the set
var svm = new KernelSupportVectorMachine(new Polynomial(2), 2);

// Create a training algorithm and learn the training data
var smo = new SequentialMinimalOptimization(svm, trainingInputs, trainingOutputs);

double trainingError = smo.Run();

// Now we can compute the validation error on the validation data:
double validationError = smo.ComputeError(validationInputs, validationOutputs);

// Return a new information structure containing the model and the errors achieved.
return new CrossValidationValues(svm, trainingError, validationError);
};
```

and then we compute:

```
// Compute the cross-validation
var result = crossvalidation.Compute();
```

now how can the best model be extracted from these folds or on what logic the framework is working if not the previously mentioned?

Comment: I think there is a bit of confusion here. Cross-validation can be used to identify the best hyper-parameters to be used with your model, but by no means you should cherry-pick the model with minimum error in cross-validation to become your "best" model.

Comment: In other words, the correct way to use cross-validation is to use it to identify the best hyperparameters, then you should create a new model using *all of your available data* using those hyperparameters and take this model as your "best" model so far.

Comment: I know it's been a few years since this question was asked... but what hyperparameters would you extract from a cross-validation to be used to train a SVM?

Answer (score 0):

I am starting to think about this in other way, may be this is a good candidate for an answer, due to lack of proper documentation, unlike encog etc. may be we are supposed to select our models by ourselves and then using each selected model run the CrossValidation against it and then can use the Mean to select the appropriate model.

Comment: The documentation page for cross-validation [has been updated with current examples for the new learning API](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_Performance_CrossValidation_2.htm). However, please see my comments to the original question and the answer by @methus below.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do the following with the result:

```
var minError = result.Models.Select(y=>y.ValidationValue).Min();
var bestModel = result.Models.Where(x=>x.ValidationValue==minError).FirstOrDefault()
```

First find out, what is the least error and then select the model that produced this error.

Comment: While this indeed can be used to select the model with minimal error, this model should *not* be used as the "best" model so far. The internal models estimated during cross-validation should not have any use other than being used to estimate the error generated by a particular choice of hyper-parameters.